# Kiu = who or which one?

Tags: word-meaning

A friend of mine begins to learn Esperanton, and he asked me this question :

> How to translate « Kiuj estas viaj instruistoj?»

I answered “Who are your teachers?”, but then, he asked me,

> Why not « Which ones are your teachers? »?

I’ve no clue why. Can someone explain to me and my friend? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Kiu* means which one of some specific group.

- *Kiu aŭto estas la via?* : Which car is yours?

If no group is specified, it is assumed that we are talking about people in general.

- *Kiuj estas estas viaj instruistoj?* : Which people = Who are your teachers?

Your friend is asking about specific group.

- *Kiuj el tiuj estas viaj instruistoj?* : Which of those = Which ones are your teachers?

Answer (score 1):

It could be both. When you ask *kiuj* you are singling them out, asking for the identity. The identity could be expressed for example as full names, or location, or otherwise.

```
Kiuj estas viaj instruistoj?
```

The answer could be:

```
John and Jane. (John kaj Jane)
```

or

```
The two standing by the exit door (la du kiuj staras ĉe la elirejo)
```